# "Package is Unavailable" Warning When Starting Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, package, themes

I am getting the following warnings every time I start Spacemacs:

```
Found 2 new package(s) to install...
--> refreshing package archive: nongnu... [3/3]
--> installing package: ef-spring-theme@dotfile... [1/2]
Package ef-spring-theme is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?
--> installing package: ef-day-theme@dotfile... [2/2]
Package ef-day-theme is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?
```

I believe I'm seeing this error because of how I'm configuring themes. Here's the applicable snippets:

```
  dotspacemacs-additional-packages
   '(
     ...
     ef-themes
     )
```

and

```
   dotspacemacs-themes
   '(
     ef-day
     ef-spring
     )
```

Is there a step I'm missing for configuring my themes? Why does emacs keep trying to install my themes based on what is listed in dotspacemacs-themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, to me, it looks logical what you are trying to do, from the [Spacemacs documentation](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#color-themes), we find that Spacemacs indeed tries to install themes declared in `dotspacemacs-themes`.

Therefore, the solution is to remove `ef-themes` from `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`, and install the individual themes via declarations in your `dotspacemacs-themes` as follows:

```lisp
dotspacemacs-themes '((ef-day :location (recipe :fetcher github
                                                :repo "protesilaos/ef-themes"))
                      (ef-spring :location (recipe :fetcher github
                                                   :repo "protesilaos/ef-themes")))
```

Comment: Goodness, I can't believe that I missed that in the docs. Once again skimming has failed me :-( Thank you for quick help!